# Matlab - the Screen() function with fillOval

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use fillOval in my Matlab program

```
width = 20;
x = round(rand()*size(3)) - width;
y = round(rand()*size(4)) - width;
Screen(wPtr, 'FillOval', [130 130 130], [x y width width]);
```

and I get the error:

```
??? Error using ==> Screen
Usage:

Screen('FillOval', windowPtr [,color] [,rect] [,perfectUpToMaxDiameter]);

Error in ==> Test at 18
       Screen(wPtr, 'FillOval', [130 130 130], [x y width width]);
```

When I replace the x, y, and width variables with values in the Screen() call, I don't get the error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rect` should be a 1x4 vector. When I use your code it is a 1x6 vector. It looks like you've accidentally overloaded the `size()` function with some `size` variable that you did not include in your example, and this is causing problems. If you name your `size` variable something else, and ensure that when you test out `[x y width width]` you get back a 1x4 vector, it should work.

Also, I assume you're talking about the PsychToolbox, but this isn't mentioned in your post either.